# how to change color of navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am creating a website in which i am using hash tag for different links such as home contact etc. but i want that my navigation button should change color to #03c1cb when the address of url describes a particular hash tab. for eg when url shows #home ,the link with name home's color should change and rest of the link should have white color. Similarly with rest of the links. Please help me how to do.I am positing my code. My html code is

```
<span><a href="#home" id="start1" class="navlink" style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:450px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;z-index:200;transition:0.5s"  onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">HOME</a></span>
<span><a href="#products" id="start2" class="navlink" style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:250px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;transition:0.5s" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</a></span>
<span><a href="#about" id="start3" class="navlink" style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:140px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;transition:0.5s" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">ABOUT US</a></span>
<span><a href="#contacts" id="start4" class="navlink" style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:20px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;transition:0.5s" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">CONTACT US</a></span>
</p>
```

and my js code is

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $j(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $j(window).width() */
      );
    }

// url change on clicking
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#start1,#start2,#start3,#start4,#start5,#start6").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = this.href,
            sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));

        $j("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $j(sectionClean).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            window.location.hash = sectionClean;
        });
    });
});
// listen for the scroll event
    $j(document).on("scroll", function() {
      console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
      $j(".anchor").each(function (idx, el) {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
          if (window.history.pushState) {
            var urlHash = "#" + $j(el).attr("id");
            window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
          }
        }
      });
    });
function big(x){

x.style.fontSize = "17px";
x.style.color="#03c1cb";
}
function small(x){

x.style.fontSize = "15px";
x.style.color="white";

}
```

please help me how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this...

```
<style>
.[ELEMENT].active{
  color: [COLOR];
}
</style>
```

Comment: He's not asking for mouseover color change. He wants active page link to have a different color..

Answer (score 0):

So really what you want to know is how to change color of an  tag.

Check out the link to my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/h892vs59/1/

In the html I have:

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
```

and in the CSS all you really have to do is remove the default text decoration that the browser uses by:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

and for all the other links:

```
a[href="home.html"] {
    color: green;
}

a[href="about.html"] {
    color: green;
}

a[href="contact.html"] {
    color: green;
}
```

what the a[href="page.html"] does is it check each  element, and only styles the  element that link to the "page.html"... so `a[href="home.html"]` will only look for `<a href="home.html">Anything can go here</a>`

Comment: calm down... what browser are you using

Comment: okay, so in CSS, the you can choose which elements to apply a style to. It also has certain features which allow you to style only certain elements with certain attributes. So if you wanted to modify an anchor tag, you would use: a { color: blue; }, whereas if you wanted to style only an anchor tag that takes you to "home.html", you could specify that in a "subselecter" using [square brackets], you can select these element by doing something like:  a[href="home.html"] { color: blue; }, which will find all anchor tags that link to "home.html" and will change their colors to blue

Comment: and when I wrote : a { text-decoration: none }, it stripped all of the links default styling, which can unlock the ability to change the colors of any link on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it on my site:

```
$('nav a').each(function () { // for each anchor in nav
    if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.toString()) { // if the anchor's href equals the windows location (converted to string)
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active'); //add a class to the anchor's parent list item
    }
});
```

This will work for a nav set up in a more typical:

```
<nav>   
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Some other page</li>
    <li>etc...</li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

---

After taking another look at your specific use case I think you can simplify things a bit and do something like this:

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/1779pccs/)**

```
 $('a').click(function () {
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: can u help me how i use it in my case. I mean nav a nd ol how to use and how the color will change ??

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra I added a simplified example that may work for you